# How to make set sprite position based on degree?

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx

I have a sprite arrow that rotates like a clock hand, I need my other sprite to spawn where the arrow is pointed.

```
//arrow rotation:
int x=Gdx.input.getX();
int y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY();

double radians= Math.atan2(y - launcherSpr.getY(), x - arrowSpr.getX());
float angle=(float)radians*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees-85;
arrowSpr.setRotation(angle);

//The other sprite that is spawned whenever the method is called
public void newBullet(){
        Sprite sprite=Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        sprite.set(bulletSpr);
        sprite.setPosition(300, 600);
        bullets.add(sprite);
}
```

Right now when the method newBullet() is called, a bullet sprite will spawn and it's Y is translated by 5(going upward by 5 pixels per frame). What I want is that the bullet will spawn based on where the arrow is pointed and go upward or downward based on the situation.

Comment: So what exactly is happening right now? No one is gonna answer your question like this.

Comment: This seems like a simple math question, not anything necessarily related to libgdx.  If it is, then the answer is a simple sine and cosine calculation based off of the angle of rotation.
`x = α*cos(θ), y = α*sin(θ)`
where `x` and `y` are the center of rotation, `θ` is the angle of rotation, and `α` is the distance from the point to create.  Just set up the tween (whether your own or the tween engine) to add a certain fraction of that each frame to get the bullet moving in the right direction.

Comment: Of course, there may be something screwy with which axis and direction counts as 0 degrees, so you may have to play around with the given angle value to find its true form.

If this isn't what you're looking for, then you need to explain a little better.